# Regex doesn't get all before

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string, but I want everything before A+.

Am I missing something?

String:

```
ABCD WWW 6587 SM A+++AB
```

Regex:

```
([0-9A-Za-z]*?) A\+
```

Output:

```
 SM A+
```

Desired Output:

```
ABCD WWW 6587 SM
```

Solution:

```
([0-9A-Za-z].*?) A\+
```

Was missing the `.` (dot)

http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks both Anirudh and Nambi Narayanan. You alerted me to the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zero-width lookahead assertion

```
^.*(?=A\+)
```

Answer (score 2):

You needed to account for the spaces. `.` is much simpler than your character class, and a lookahead like `(?=...)` will allow you to match but ignore the `A+`. So, this regex works:

```
(.*?)(?= A\+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8D3jrz7E2Ph3GUme)

**Output:**

```
ABCD WWW 6587 SM
```

**PHP code:**

```
$str= "ABCD WWW 6587 SM A+++AB";
preg_match('~(.*?)(?= A\+)~', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
$str=" ABCD WWW 6587 SM A+++AB";
echo preg_replace('~(.*)A\+.*~','$1',$str);
```

OUTPUT

```
ABCD WWW 6587 SM
```